# Where are the files for a package?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp, hunchentoot

Following this [clisp basic website tutorial](http://www.adampetersen.se/articles/lispweb.htm) it asks me to define a package to persist the code:

```
(defpackage :retro-games
   (:use :cl :cl-who :hunchentoot :parenscript))
```

However, I cannot work out where my code is being persisted. Where are the files?

NB: I have only one day's experience with lisp!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are the files? They are where you want them.

1. Create a new file anywhere you want.
2. Put the definitions into the file.
3. Done

Lisp can `LOAD` files and you can use `COMPILE-FILE`.

In Common Lisp there no connections between files, the location of a file and a package. The package definition just defines a namespace to symbols. But this is not necessarily connected to a file. Some tools help maintain something called a *system*, which is a collection of files, which can be compiled and loaded together.

To get a basic understanding how to use Common Lisp I recommend reading [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) by Peter Seibel.

Comment: And [ASDF](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/) is a tool to automate the process of `LOAD`ing these files.